# How to use HiDPI mode / scaling in Shotcut?

Tags: linux, video-editing, high-dpi

How to increase UI size, density, font size, and UI scaling to HiDPI mode in Shotcut (using QT) open source editing program?

Answer (score 0):

There is no DPI or font size settings within Shotcut. But the program is built with QT and scaling environmental flags enabled.

If you add `export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.25` to your bash profile, or just run in terminal before you run `shotcut` the scaling will update. Can play around with the values to increase or decrease.

(Adding question, because finding this information was not easy at the time.